# How do i predict data with python sklearn linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

[Sales.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDvH9.png) I have sales figures on an excel file for Jan to June and i want to predict july figures using sklearn linear regression.

I got this far.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = pd.read_excel('Sales.xlsx')

x = [ ]
y = [ ]


model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x, y)

x_predict = []
y_predict = model.predict(x_predict)
print(y_predict)
```

Comment: Is that suposed to be an uppercase X?

Comment: @kpie no it supposed to be common

Comment: Show your excel file.

Comment: Can you show the values of y_predict and define more about the expect result ?

Comment: @GilseungAhn I am a new user and i am getting trouble to upload my excel file

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @GilseungAhn  i added a link to my excel file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So x would be slice of the columns that you want to use when trying to predict, and y is the column that has the known values (here, sales).

So, for example, assume you are trying to predict sales from demand and GDP, then x and y would be as follows:

```
x = df.loc[:, ['demand', 'GDP']]
y = df.loc[:, 'sales']
```

The `x_predict` line should be omitted. You are never trying to predict x, which are the features or values that are the basis of your prediction.

The other problem is that you are not splitting the dataset into train and test, so there are no values left to predict based on the model.